# mViewPager.setCurrentItem showing all pages in between

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager

I have implement PageViewer with multiple fragment child view(Say A, B, C). There are chance when control can directly navigate to either of A/B/C. So I used `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position)`

but if I set say to position "C" view position, then it show first View A and B for a moment and then it show View C. Is there any way to avoid in between fragment view showing !

**EDIT:**
I found just to pass additionally parameter "false" to disable viewing of in-between view but still if I go back to previous page so it show me skipped page as well. So basically view pager load additional page for you to [perform optimization](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29), default is 1. But what if do not want to show back track View which I have skipped.

Any suggestion!

Comment: I think this is a page transfer animation and you can override the default or set your custom

Comment: @mmlooloo any suggestion to override this !

Comment: I implement some custom for my app but here is public abstract void transformPage (View page, float position) function I think you must change, but I am not exactly sure

Comment: mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position) with an extra parameter to "false" solve showing in between fragment, but even when I perform back to previous screen, it show in-between fragment first before to reach required fragment. So is there any way to just not launch not-required fragment.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by performing back to previous screen, another trick is override pressback by using mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position) with false parameter

Comment: Yes that I did and it solve not to show in between view which I skipped but when I do back swipe on Page Viewer it still show me skipped view, Please check edit question.